# How to set prettier indents?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, filetype-javascript

I have `set tabstop` to 4.

But when I use prettier, it defaults my indentations to 2 spaces.

How do I change this?

I am using the coc prettier extension.

```
const thing = () => {

    var hi = 1;  //tabstop does this
  var hi2 = 2;   // prettier formats to this

}
```

Comment: Configure prettier to use 4 spaces (?) or `:setlocal tabstop=2` maybe?

Comment: I guess the question is how to configure coc prettier to do that. I have read through the docs and I am struggling to understand how to accomplish that,

Comment: _e.g._, https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: For anyone who cares, the missing piece for me was "where" to add the settings. Turns out you need to add the prettier settings to the coc-settings.json file. Thanks, Ben for your support.

Comment: you're quite welcome; please add an answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is facing a similar issue, when you use the prettier extension via coc-prettier, you need to put the configuration options inside the `coc-settings.json` file.

To solve my issue of prettier tab spaces, I added this:

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4
```

Finally, this page gives a full list of all your other options. https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html